# Expected Value of the number of letters we need to draw from the alphabet

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, coupon-collector

We draw letters (a-z) independently and uniformly at random from the alphabet with replacement. If we draw a collection of letters, then we say that we can write a word when the collections contains all the letters needed to spell the word. For example, if we draw ‘a’, ‘c’ and ‘t’, then this collection writes the word ‘cat’, but also ‘act’, ‘at’ and ‘a’.

Let $N$ be the random variable that denotes the number of letters we needed to draw before we can write ‘rowel’ for the first time. Find $E[N]$ and $\text{Var}[N]$.

Could someone help me by showing me how to approach this question?

Comment: This question was posted in very similar form $5$ days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3617525) but then deleted by the user. Please let us know where you encountered this problem. Please take note of our [contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774).

Comment: If he hasn't responded with the source of the problem I believe the solution should not be posted.

Comment: This problem was from an exam that occurred last week for my university course. In my preparation for the re-examination I am trying to understand the problems from this exam. From what I understand from the contest problem policy this is not a contest problem anymore as the examination has already been?

Answer (score 1):

At first you have probability $\frac5{26}$ on each try to draw a letter you need. Once you’ve succeeded, you have probability $\frac4{26}$ on each try to draw another letter you still need, and so on. Thus $N$ is the sum of $5$ independently [geometrically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) variables, whose expectations and variances you can add to find the expectation and variance of $N$.

This is a truncated version of the [coupon collector’s problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). You’ll find a lot of related questions under the corresponding tag that was added to your question.

Comment: Oh yeah, I messed up the Coupon Collector's problem. My bad.